# "We are familiar" improvement

Tags: phrases, expressions, american-english, business-language

I have this,"We are familiar with the sport activities", sentence but to me it's a bit awkward and I need to improve it a little bit. I need to improve "We are familiar" part, and I am kind of stuck with that, so any idea how to do so?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: I would make it "sports activities" by the way.

Comment: Do you really mean *familiar* (which can mean anything from *have heard of* to *know all about*) sporting activities? Or do you really mean you actively *engage* in organised sports?

Comment: Please note that 'kinda' is not a recognised abbreviation in English. It is only used when quoting dialog (or in song lyrics).

Comment: kinda http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/kinda is a contraction, lots of folks say it, and write it :)

Answer (score 1):

Your sentence is OK, except for the **"the"** before sports activities.  I suggest "acquainted" which is about just the same. Look at these examples, in order of familiarity:

- "I never enjoyed sports activities and kept away from them"
- **"I'm acquainted with sports activities"**  ( Known by or familiar with)
- "I sometimes participate in sports activities"
- "I often participate in sports activities"
- "I'm a born athlete"